# Is it possible to setup Gerrit for GIT without using per person SSH certificates

Tags: git, ssh, ldap, gerrit

I am trying to setup GIT + GERRIT infrastructure for my team. We are part of bigger company. Company with procedures and practices.

Upto now we have been using SVN, which allows for LDAP authentication. We basically were able to commit using username and password.

Now I have been struggling for several days with the GIT configuration. I know that theoretically speaking it is possible to configure GIT to use such pairs of username/password for the commits instead of SSH certificates.

However, I am pretty decided on code reviews and GERRIT. Now as I started reading it seems that **there is no way to configure account in GERRIT if you do not configure SSH key for it**. This seems to me like double authentication as we already expose Gerrit through https and have credentials for controlling the access. Also I do not think I have the influence to make the admins either:

- provide per account SSH keys through the LDAP
- configure the keys for each instance of Gerrit (as we have many repositories we want to migrate)

Currently if I do not find a way around that maybe my quest for migration to GIT will fail. Is there a way to configure GIT to work with gerrit without providing per person SSH certificate? I still need to be able to distinguish as commiters all the users in significant LDAP directory.

Comment: Given that the SSH key setup is self-administered by the users, what's the problem? Anyway, Gerrit supports password-based authentication for HTTP/HTTPS uploads, see https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-upload.html#http.

Comment: @MagnusBäck Thank you for your answer. Abt 1st part - we have central unit that assigns access rights, thus self administered sounds as not working. ABT second part - yes I have come to this, but I might be a bit confused, isn't this pseaking about authentication for Gerrit login? Still the commit reuirees SSH key or am I wrong? I saw this section which troubles me: http://gerrit.googlecode.com/svn/documentation/2.0/user-upload.html#ssh `Each user uploading changes to Gerrit must configure one or more SSH public keys.`

Comment: I still think you're misunderstanding the self-administration part. What's the problem with the users running `ssh-keygen` and pasting the contents of their public key into the Gerrit web interface? This will authenticate them to Gerrit, but it's still the administrator that chooses which resources each user has access to. The documentation I linked to is specifically for pushes, not the web interface. The documentation _you_ link to is over four years old and very much out of date.

Comment: i think that is not possible to use ssh with password, only https which has it own password generation method

Comment: @HiB that's perfectly fine with me. I already have it. The queston is whether i can skip the SSH per person keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to configure GIT to work with gerrit without providing per person SSH certificate?

Yes.  Gerrit supports encrypted git communication through either ssh or https.  ssh requires keys, https uses a username/(Gerrit-generated)password.  You can disable ssh if you don't want to use keys - this is what Google does for their Gerrit servers (see https://android-review.googlesource.com/)

> Also I do not think I have the influence to make the admins either:
>
> - provide per account SSH keys through the LDAP
> - configure the keys for each instance of Gerrit (as we have many repositories we want to migrate)

Fortunately you don't need to do this with Gerrit.  Gerrit uses a built-in ssh server, it does not use the server's standard ssh server.  Users create their own ssh keys locally, and upload them to Gerrit through the web interface.  You don't need the admins to provide or configure keys.

Comment: My current problem is that I can not get git push to work with gerrit. Am I to configure each gerrit user as linux user in order to configure the git repo correctly? Which user is Gerrit using for the commits?

Comment: No - the Gerrit users don't need a system account at all.  Gerrit runs its own SSH server, it does not tie into the system ssh server or use system accounts.  Have you uploaded your ssh key to Gerrit's web UI (if you are pushing over ssh)?  What commands are you using to push?  It sounds like this issue might belong in a separate discussion.  Gerrit uses the user running the server for all commits, but accepts pushes from users with permissions in Gerrit.

Comment: You seem to be right for everything you have said. It seems I had to provide http password in the settings of the user I was making attempts with for the push the succeed. I continue to struggle to try to get this working with the ldap configured passwords.

Comment: I'm still wondering what kind of sense does a Gerrit-generated HTTP password make when the user already has a HTTP user AND password to log in to the site. Not to mention that if the site login name is set to the LDAP UPN attribute (i.e.: john.smith@foo.com) Gerrit trims the domain on its own. So you get a different username AND password. Ridiculously awful.